# Surfacing large image tags that require api authentication

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver4

I'm working with a system that is currently switching from using cookie authentication to identity server. The front end of the application is a SPA using KnockoutJS. The SPA has access to a WebAPI scope for its content.

We currently have code in place to allow the SPA to get the bearer token for the Identity Server and make ajax calls to the API passing the token in the Authentication header. The problem we're now encountering is how to replace some image tags src attributes that were previously linking directly to the WebAPI.

An example is:

```
<img alt="Secure image" src="/api/username/secureimage?v=1464277579255" />
```

This was talking to the web api with a method signature similar to the method below (cut down for this post)

```
[HttpGet("")]
[Route("api/{username}/[controller]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SecureImage(string username)
{
    var secureImage = await _manager.GetSecureImageAsync(username);
    if (secureImage != null)
        return File(secureImage.FileName, secureImage.ContentType);
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

One approach we've seen is to change the API to return a base64 encoded image and use ajax to request the image string which can then be set as the src e.g.

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

This isn't an option with our current system though since there is a size limit on image files that can be surfaced using this method (which seems to vary from browser to browser) and a lot of our images are too large for this method.

Is there any other way to pass the large images to the browser securely?